# ListView containing TabHost with other ListViews

Tags: android, android-listview, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I want to create a `ListView` with the last row showing a `TabHost` with two tabs. I would like to load another `ListView` for each tab. For this, I've created three XML files.

The main.xml is where I'm loading the initial list. The mainlistdata.xml is how each row of the list is presented. And the last xml is tabslayout.xml. This layout is used for the last row on the main listview. It will load the tabhost. [Here is the code](http://pastebin.com/spvCrhpJ) with all the xml:

My main class is this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<testData> myData = new ArrayList<testData>();
    ListView listContent;
    TestAdapter dataAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String[] aString = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };

        for (int i = 0; i < aString.length; i++) {
            myData.add(new testData(i, aString[i]));
        }

        listContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainlist);
        dataAdapter = new TestAdapter(this, myData,1);
        listContent.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
}
```

And this is the class that loads the content on the listviews and where I set the tabhost:

```
public class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<testData> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<testData> data;
    private ListView listContent,listContent2;
    public TabHost tabs;
    TestAdapter dataAdapter;
    private int choice;
    public TestAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<testData> data, int choice) {
        super(context, R.layout.mainlistdata, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.choice = choice;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView;
        if (choice == 1) {
            if (position == data.size()-1) {
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabslayout, parent, false);

                TextView first = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dataTitle);
                TextView second = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dataValue);
                TextView third = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dataValueString);

                first.setText("Item " + data.get(position).getIntValue());
                second.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).getIntValue()));
                third.setText(data.get(position).getStringValue());

                tabs = (TabHost) rowView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
                tabs.setup();
                TabSpec tab1 = tabs.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
                TabSpec tab2 = tabs.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
                tab1.setContent(R.id.tabOne);
                tab2.setContent(R.id.tabTwo);
                tab1.setIndicator("One");
                tab2.setIndicator("two");
                tabs.addTab(tab1);
                tabs.addTab(tab2);
                tabs.setup();

                listContent = (ListView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listOne);
                dataAdapter = new TestAdapter(context, data,2);
                listContent.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                listContent2 = (ListView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listTwo);
                dataAdapter = new TestAdapter(context, data,3);
                listContent2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            } else {
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainlistdata, parent, false);
                TextView first = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dataTitle);
                TextView second = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dataValue);
                TextView third = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dataValueString);

                first.setText("Item " + data.get(position).getIntValue());
                second.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).getIntValue()));
                third.setText(data.get(position).getStringValue());
            }
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainlistdata, parent, false);
            TextView first = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dataTitle);
            TextView second = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dataValue);
            TextView third = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dataValueString);

            first.setText("Item tab1 " + data.get(position).getIntValue());
            second.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).getIntValue()));
            third.setText(data.get(position).getStringValue());
        } else {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainlistdata, parent, false);
            TextView first = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dataTitle);
            TextView second = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dataValue);
            TextView third = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dataValueString);

            first.setText("Item tab2 " + data.get(position).getIntValue());
            second.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).getIntValue()));
            third.setText(data.get(position).getStringValue());
        }
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

As you can see on the next image, I'm loading the data and then I'm loading the tabs. The problem is that each tab is only loading the first row of the data. Any idea How can I solve this?
[image] [image]

Comment: Looks like your count incorrect, what is the data you set for the adapter?

Comment: Hi shem. See on the main class. The data is an integer and an letter. The images are only showing the last part of the listviews. The main list shows what is expected, integers from 0 to 25 and letter from a to z.The tabhost is loaded correctly but the listview in each of the tabs is only showing the first item of the data

Comment: when does `choice` became 2 (or not 1)?

Comment: See testadapter  class.  It's for loading the list on tab one and two

Comment: yes of course, this won't work: As you will have two "scroll" inside each other. I advice you use these buttons (instead of tabhost) to load more items inside the same listview

Comment: @SherifelKhatib Hello. Thanks for your answer. What do you mean with " advice you use these buttons " what are these buttons?

Comment: @Favolas I meant (use buttons instead of the tab host to load more items in the same listview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sherif elKhatib already said in his comment having a `ListView` in another `ListView` should be avoided. The solution for your problems is using a single `ListView` along with different row types to give the illusion of having tabs in the `ListView` containing other `ListViews`, all handled by a custom adapter. Based on your example, you would have four row types:

- normal row(the ones with the letters)
- one row containing the tabs
- two row types for each of the pseudo `ListViews`(unless your tabs should have the same row appearance in which case you would have a single tab row type)

To implement these row types you would need to use the `getItemViewType()` and `getViewTypeCount()` method of an adapter:

```
// different row types
private static final int NORMAL_ROW = 0;
private static final int TAB_ROW = 1;
private static final int TAB1_TYPE = 2;
private static final int TAB2_TYPE = 3;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position < mData.size()) {
            // we are in the initial list's range so it's a normal row
        return NORMAL_ROW;
    } else if (position == mData.size()) {
        // we are at the tab level, so it's a tab row
        return TAB_ROW;
    } else {
        // based on the current selected tab(0 by default) we have
        // either a tab 1 row type or tab 2 row type
        return mCurrentSelectedTab == 0 ? TAB1_TYPE : TAB2_TYPE;
    }

}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // if your list-tabs need different row types then you'll need to
    // make the calculations here and update appropriately
    return 4;
}
```

In the `getView()` you would inflate the proper layout(your layouts) based on those row layout types and also set the data. The adapter will also need to handle the user selecting a tab to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` and update the `ListView` with the proper row type(and data) for the tab part of it.

You can see the [whole sample here](https://github.com/luksprog/DroidPlayground/blob/master/src/com/luksprog/dp/adapter/ListWithTabs.java), also have a look at the [xml layouts used](https://github.com/luksprog/DroidPlayground/tree/master/res/layout), it should be quite easy to understand.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Many, many thanks. Now just have to learn the code :)

Comment: Hi. I've managed to make the code you provided work with 7 types of rows. `TAB3_TYPE` and `TAB4_TYPE` and an initial row `INIT_ROW` that is inflated at the start of main list `getItemViewType(int position) { if (position == 0) { return INIT_ROW;}…`I know want to inflate a new kind of row. This row should be inflated at the end of the 4 lists that are shown when using the tabs. Can you point me in some direction? I've tried a bunch of things but none of them worked :(